# Iterate over a Js array with two objects (firebase)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase

I'm using firebase to make a chat application. I stumbled upon a little problem.
When making requests to the firebase database, firebase will return a JSON or JS object back (I'm new to this so I don't really know).

This is the structure of my database:

[image]

The first ID under the message tree is the client's ID which I get when a cidst connects to the application. The id's just below are the client'ID with whom the logged client chatted with and the Id below that is firebase generated ID for each message.

With this code (see below) I'm listening on the database to see if any messages have been added for notification purposes.

```
var ref = database.ref('messages/81k44hlET5cq2AorxLDxD1DeXV52/');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);
function gotData(data) {

  var msgs = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(msgs);
  console.log(msgs);

  messages = new Array();
  timestamp = new Array();
  type = new Array();

  for(var keys in msgs) {
    if (msgs.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
      console.log(keys + " -> " + msgs[keys]);
      messages.push(msgs[keys]);
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the code:

[image]

I'm getting an array with two objects. Until here everything works fine.

My problem is that I can't figure out how I can get my message properties from here using JavaScript since the Message-IDs are unknown.

What I mean is that I can't access the properties doing `msgs[keys].id.message` for example since ID is unknown.

Comment: So do you wnat to use fb object in your JS

Comment: Instead `console.log(keys + " -> " + msgs[keys]);` do this `console.log(keys , " -> " , msgs[keys]);`

Comment: I'm trying to get the msg properties from the object (message, timestamp, ...)

Comment: @Prashant I'm gonna try right now ( im new to js as well )

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k01qr2 This is what im getting after changing the line still don't understand how i can get the message properties using this tho :c

Comment: Ok i figured it out thanks to @Prashant, I updated my code to this and i can now get to my message properties. Thanks!  if (msgs.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
                console.log(keys , " -> " , msgs[keys]);
                messages.push(msgs[keys]);
                var k = msgs[keys];
                for(var keys in k){

                    console.log( k[keys]);
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
        var ref = database.ref('messages/81k44hlET5cq2AorxLDxD1DeXV52/');
        ref.on('value', gotData, errData);
        function gotData(data)
        {


            var msgs = data.val();
            var keys = Object.keys(msgs);
            console.log(msgs);

            messages = new Array();
            timestamp = new Array();
            type = new Array();


            for(var keys in msgs)
            {
                if (msgs.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
                    console.log(keys , " -> " , msgs[keys]);
                    messages.push(msgs[keys]);
                    var k = msgs[keys];
                    for(var keys in k){

                        console.log( k[keys]);
                    }
                    //
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post answers if they're not actual answers. Instead edit your question directly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your JavaScript object with the `.forEach` method, use `Object.entries` for this.

In the following code snippet, I am logging all message objects

```js
const messages = {
  kjzn5ef6ke2zlfzn: {
    h6qjopdbgs5d6mv7f: {
      gd73g4d5d9dvtjzj15: {
        message: "k",
        seend: "true",
        timestamp: "26/6/2018 20",
        type: "send"
      },
      kdaz8bamd6kprmq78: {
        message: "k",
        seend: "true",
        timestamp: "26/6/2018 20",
        type: "send"
      }
    }
  }
};

Object.entries(messages).forEach(([id1, a]) => {
  Object.entries(a).forEach(([id11, b]) => {
    Object.entries(b).forEach(([id111, message]) => {
      console.log(id1, '=>', id11, '=>', id111, ':', message)
    });
  });
});
```